# use for COUNT command to create query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

**Below shows my original MY SQL table.**

```
SELECT name, COUNT(city) AS "count_no"
FROM emp
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count_no DESC;
```

[image]

**I need following result.**

[image]

SAM has 4 records. But there are city of London in two records. 
I need **How many different cities in SAM's Records**.
I did lots of queries, but I couldn't create my SQL query.

Comment: add an inner query instead of emp table (select distinct name, city from emp).

Comment: @wxyz: no need for nested query

Answer (score 4):

Add DISTINCT to the count parameter:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT city) AS "count_no"
FROM emp
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count_no DESC;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT city) AS "count_no"
FROM emp
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count_no DESC;
```

Comment: +1 for screen shot - lol. I'm claiming a higher degree of difficultly btw - I thumbed my answer on an iPhone, and copy-paste is no picnic on them either! :)

Comment: @Bohemian: +1 for the difficulty :)